# Export 3D layers automatically in CityEngine to FBX?

Tags: export, 3d, cityengine

How to automatically export all layers in a scene in CityEngine to corresponding FBX? Is there a batch processing or a programming approach for exporting them to FBX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an Advanced license of CityEngine you have the possibilities to script your export using python which makes your live pretty easy. You can do something like:

```
from scripting import *
ce = CE()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    layers = ce.getObjectsFrom(ce.scene(), ce.isLayer)
    for layer in layers:
        objects = ce.getObjectsFrom(layer, ce.isShape)
        ems = FBXExportModelSettings()
        ems.setOutputPath("YOUR PATH")
        #set other options
        ce.setSelection(objects)
        ce.export(objects, ems)
```

Clearly you can also select different objects than shapes from the layer.

If you don't have an Advanced license you are stuck with right clicking a layer, hitting "Select Objects", and then going to File -> Export Models... and exporting every layer manually to some format (e.g. OBJ) and then using other tools to convert this to FBX.